# convert int to use it with concat()

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

i wrote this sql statement:

```
SELECT concat(
            'INSERT INTO dev_sys_index (name,tableid,descrition) VALUES (idx_',
            name,
            ',',
            id,
            ',eindeutige Kombination aus abfid und parentid);') 
    FROM dev_sys_tables 
    WHERE datenmodell=350
```

However the output is only a wall of hex numbers because `id` is an integer. i have tried many things like cast an converts the id to a string, `CAST( id as varchar)`., but nothing worked. I am still getting this error message.

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'varchar ),',eindeutige Kombination aus abfid und parentid);'

)

Any help would be apprecticated!

works fine:

```
concat(
    'INSERT INTO dev_sys_index (name,tableid,descrition) VALUES (idx_',
    name,
    ',',
    cast(id as char),
    ',eindeutige Kombination aus abfid und parentid);')
```

getting only a wall of hexnumbers:

```
concat(
    'INSERT INTO dev_sys_index (name,tableid,descrition) VALUES (idx_',
    name,
    ',',
    id,
    ',eindeutige Kombination aus abfid und parentid);')
```

**UPDATE
Problem solved. I have to use `cast(whatever as char)` instead of `cast(whatever as varchar)`**

Comment: What is it exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: i am trying to creat an insert statement with the concat and concat only accept string variables, so the main problem is to convert id from int to string to use it in this concat statement.

Comment: CONCAT in mysql can take integer as parameters. `CONCAT(1, 2)` will give `12`

Comment: i know.... thats my problem

Comment: i try this `SELECT concat('INSERT INTO dev_sys_index (name,tableid,descrition) VALUES (idx_',"asd",',',1,',eindeutige Kombination aus abfid und parentid);')` and it works.....

Comment: yes this worked for me too, but not with the id variable which returns an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to convert or cast at all (and you should have used `cast(whatever as char)` instead of `varchar` anyway).

You're missing `"` around `eindeutige Kombination aus abfid und parentid` or your insert statement won't work:

```
SELECT concat('INSERT INTO dev_sys_index (name,tableid,descrition) VALUES (idx_',name,',',id,',"eindeutige Kombination aus abfid und parentid");') 
FROM dev_sys_tables 
WHERE datenmodell=350
```

P.S.: Here's the [manual entry](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cast-functions.html) that states that

> The type for the result can be one of the following values:
>
> - BINARY[(N)]
> - CHAR[(N)]
> - DATE
> - DATETIME
> - DECIMAL[(M[,D])]
> - SIGNED [INTEGER]
> - TIME
> - UNSIGNED [INTEGER]

Proof:

```
mysql> select id, id from tasks;
+------+------+
| id   | id   |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
|    2 |    2 |
|    3 |    3 |
+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT concat('INSERT INTO dev_sys_index (name,tableid,descrition) VALUES (idx_',id,',',id,',"eindeutige Kombination aus abfid und parentid");') from tasks;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| concat('INSERT INTO dev_sys_index (name,tableid,descrition) VALUES (idx_',id,',',id,',"eindeutige Kombination aus abfid und parentid");') |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| INSERT INTO dev_sys_index (name,tableid,descrition) VALUES (idx_1,1,"eindeutige Kombination aus abfid und parentid");                     |
| INSERT INTO dev_sys_index (name,tableid,descrition) VALUES (idx_2,2,"eindeutige Kombination aus abfid und parentid");                     |
| INSERT INTO dev_sys_index (name,tableid,descrition) VALUES (idx_3,3,"eindeutige Kombination aus abfid und parentid");                     |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

P.S.: One can see here, that you're also missing quotes around `idx_1` in the column `name`.

Comment: no ',eindeutige Kombination aus abfid und parentid);' is aleady a string. when i remove id and put a string varaible there, it worked finde...so i habe nothing to do with this. i know the error message look like that is the problem, but it isnt.

Comment: but you are right. i should use cast(whatever as char) instead of cast(whatever as varchar) that was the problem. thanks!

Comment: @kai No, you're confusing some commas and single quotes in concat function. Format your code properly and this is less likely to happen. I tried your query with my adjustments and it works just fine. No casting or converting needed.

Comment: pls look my edit...for me it worked without your quotes if i convert the int! if i dont convert its also executed, but i only get hexnumbers.

Comment: Yes, the CONCAT() works, but the insert statement will not! That's what I'm trying to tell you.

Comment: ahhh okay, thats possible, but i have never tested the insert statement, thats the next step. but thanks for the hint.

Comment: Updated my answer. Then I saw, that you're also missing quotes around `idx_` in the name column. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CONVERT function, I think that will solve your case

Comment: i tried many things like CONVERT(VARCHAR,id) but nothing worked. i searched a long time on the internet.